# Is it possible to root Samsung Xcover3(sm-g388F) 5.1.1

Tags: rooting

Is it possible to root Samsung Xcover3 sm-g388F on Android 5.1.1? 
Read in a lot of forums that it is not possible, but also read in numerous Times that it is possible. Can you Clarion this to me?
 Best reegards Pierre Hellner Gothenburg Sweden

Comment: Check [this](http://www.theandroidsoul.com/samsung-galaxy-xcover-3-root-twrp-recovery-84011/?PageSpeed=noscript) please :)